# UIView: how to restrict touches to it exclusively

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to display a modal dialog i.e. user should not be able to touch anything under it, unless he dismisses the dialog first. `[self setExclusiveTouch:YES]` doesn't seem to help, user can still click the buttons below the dialog.

any ideas?

Comment: When you say "display a modal dialog," do you mean one presented with `presentModalViewController:animated:`? There is [an example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) in the documentation that is useful. It pushes the view along with a navigation controller, on which you can place a back button that uses a delegate to dismiss the modal view controller.

Comment: One way could be to place a transparent `UIView` below your modal dialog view, sized as the `UIWindow` and with userInteractionEnabled set to NO.

Comment: @mxb That's the simplest way to solve this problem, and you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to place a transparent `UIView` below your modal dialog view, sized as the `UIWindow` and with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`.